# How to add rows to the front of a dataframe based on date index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe which looks like this. `Date` is a `datetime` index. Each date has 1 entry.

```
              Count
Date             
2020-08-14     2
2020-08-15     2
2020-08-16     1
```

How can I insert rows to the head of the dataframe, with the values being 0? The number of rows inserted is based on a specified date. E.g. if date is `2020-08-09`, rows with dates `2020-08-09` to `2020-08-13` are inserted. Output looks like this:

```
             Count
Date          
2020-08-09     0
2020-08-10     0
2020-08-11     0
2020-08-12     0
2020-08-13     0 
2020-08-14     2
2020-08-15     2
2020-08-16     1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `reindex` with a new date range:

```
dr = pd.date_range('08-09-2020', '08-16-2020', freq='1D')

df = df.reindex(dr).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat()`

```
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,8,9), dt.datetime(2020,8,13)),
                  "Count":0}).set_index("Date"),
    df
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a row with index `Timestamp('2020-08-09')`. `Sort_index` and `asfreq`

```
df.loc[pd.Timestamp('2020-08-09')] = 0
df = df.sort_index().asfreq('D', method='pad')

Out[63]:
            Count
Date
2020-08-09      0
2020-08-10      0
2020-08-11      0
2020-08-12      0
2020-08-13      0
2020-08-14      2
2020-08-15      2
2020-08-16      1
```